# spring rabbit amqp @RabbitListener configure min and max number of consumers

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using spring amqp rabbit @RabbitListener annotation
 from : artifact spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE
I wonder if there is a way to configure for each queue the number of consumers ?
I have been digging in the documentation and found nothing yet , is there a way to configure in the related container for each queue the number of consumers ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean number of consumer threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure the concurrency via the [container factory bean as shown in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven).

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
    return factory;
}
```

If you are using Spring Boot, which creates the factory bean for you, you can configure them using properties.

If you want a fixed number of consumers, just omit the `max`.

If you want different settings for each listener, you need a different factory for each set of settings. You would then reference the particular container factory for a `@RabbitListener` in its `containerFactory` property.

Comment: you should add that :    @RabbitListener(queues = STATUS_QUEUE_NAME ,containerFactory=STATUS_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY) couse I have several places where I use it .

    @Bean(STATUS_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY)
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory statusListenerContainerFactory() { ... }

Comment: @Gary I set the min and max limit by adding the following statements:



    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);

Now at a time, only 3 requests are getting executed parallelly. My understanding is that max 10 requests should get executed simultaneously. by setting these 2 parameters.

Please tell me where am i going wrong

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than commenting on an existing question. But, no, it means we start at 3 and will slowly increase to 10 **if there are enough messages in the queue**.. The algorithm is [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#listener-concurrency). With the default settings, if there are enough messages, a new consumer will be added every 10 seconds.

Comment: @GaryRussell My apologies. Here is my question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017401/rabbitmq-concurrent-consumers-in-spring-boot

Can you please reply there?