# Rabbitmq concurrent consumers in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using @RabbitListener annotation and SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory bean for parallel execution of rabbitmq messages and setting the min and max concurrent consumers in the following way :

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(MIN_RABBIT_CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(MAX_RABBIT_CONCURRENT_CONSUMERS);
    factory.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(1);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}
```

The min limit is 3 and the max limit is 10. With this configuration, only 3 messages are getting executed parallelly, even though there are 12 messages in the queue.

Please tell me what is wrong with the config?

Answer (score 7):

You can create max concurrent consumers using rabbitMQ annotation

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "your-queue-name", concurrency = "4")
public void customCheck(Object requestObject) {
    // process
}
```

Comment: Can concurrency be changed every time this method get called?

Comment: S Khandelwal it will increase till the concurrent number you have added. It will not consume requests more then given concurrency.

Answer (score 6):

With the default configuration, a new consumer will be added every 10 seconds if the other consumers are still busy.

The algorithm (and properties to affect it) is [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#listener-concurrency).

Comment: Documentation moved to https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#listener-concurrency

Comment: Thanks; link fixed.

Comment: Don't ask new questions on year-old answers. Yes, it comes standard with Spring AMQP. If you need more information, ask a new question.