# How to create Multiple instances of object using spring IOC when application starts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have below is Listener class.My application is spring boot application.  I am instantiating it in my configuration class. But i want 100 instances have to be created when application starts & when application stops all instances objects have to be closed. It just like what we did in connection pooling. Can any one suggest best way to achieve this? Below are my listener class And piece of code used in my configuration class to instantiate Listener class.

```
@EnableRabbit
public class SubscriberGeneralQueue1 {

     /*@Autowired
        @Qualifier("asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate")
    private AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate;*/

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    @Autowired
    private GeneralProcess generalProcess;



    List <RequestPojo> requestPojoGeneral = new ArrayList<RequestPojo>();

    @RabbitHandler
    @Async
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
    public void subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload RequestPojo sampleRequestMessage, Message message) throws InterruptedException {

        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();


        //requestPojoGeneral.add(sampleRequestMessage);
        //System.out.println("List size issssss:" +requestPojoGeneral.size() );
        //generalProcess.processRequestObjectslist(requestPojoGeneral);
        generalProcess.processRequestObjects(sampleRequestMessage);

        System.out.println("message in general listener is:" + sampleRequestMessage.getDistance());
        System.out.println("Message payload is:" + sampleRequestMessage);
        System.out.println("Message payload1111 is:" + message );

        //return requestPojoGeneral;

    }


}
```

I am instantiating the above class in my configuration class

```
@Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public SubscriberGeneralQueue1 SubscriberGeneralQueue1(){
        return new SubscriberGeneralQueue1();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an object pool?  But why do you need 100 instances?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have 50 k obejects pushed to queue. I have one listener class instances which listens for objects and processes. To handle the load i want to distribute 50k objects for 100 instances of listeners so that i can empty queue quickly by processing all message objects.

Comment: See the currency attribute of @RabbitListener, e.g., `@RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue" currency="100")`

Comment: will it create 100 instances to handle Queue load?

Comment: Yes - from what I understand there is proxy factory which will create up to 100 instances.  [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169979/spring-rabbit-amqp-rabbitlistener-configure-min-and-max-number-of-consumers?rq=1) might help.

Comment: Thanks Andrew . I will try this one and will see how it performs.

Comment: Andrew unfortunately i am not able to find property  concurrency inside  @RabbitListener annotation.

Comment: Check the version.  You might need to configure the factory manually (see linked question in other comment).